# How to separate group by if value exists in multiple categories

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE users_category 
(
    user_id int,
    category_id int
);

insert into users_category (user_id, category_id)
values (100, 1), (100, 2), (103, 4), (105, 4), (106, 2), (107, 1)
```

Then I'm trying to calculate how much users use categories like :

```
select category_id,count(*)
from users_category
group by category_id
```

Response is :

```
category_id   count
4               2
1               2
2               2
```

How to add logic if users exists in more than one category , calculate it in other category.

For example user 100 exists in category 1 and 2 and i will not calculate it for both category-s . I want add new category ex. 99 and must add users there.

Response must be like :

```
category_id  count
4             2
1             1
2             1
99            1  (user who was in both category)
```

How to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to aggregate first at the user level and then at the category level:

```
select category_id, count(*)
from (select user_id,
             (case when min(category_id) = max(category_id) then min(category_id)
                   else 99
              end) as category_id
      from users_category uc
      group by user_id
     ) uc
group by category_id;
```